# Bazinga Expose Translation Bundle does not translate

Tags: javascript, symfony, translation

I have a DOM element that is created via ajax
something like this:

```
$('.inner').append('<p>Salva Foto</p>');
```

my Twig is composed

```
{% javascripts
***my js***
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bazingaexposetranslation/js/translator.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('bazinga_exposetranslation_js') }}"></script>
```

my locale is it, and in my bundle i have messages.en.yml (I tried with .xlf) with:

```
Salva Foto: Save Photo
```

Of the Default Locale is it, now I'm trying the translation for the English language

if I look at the files uploaded from my browser, I see a javascript file: en
and contains

```
Translator.locale = 'en';
Translator.defaultDomains = ["messages"];
Translator.add("messages:Salva Foto", "Save Photo");
```

but the paragraph created via javascript is not translated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS you must use the Object Translator created with Bazinga. If you try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(Translator.get("messages:Salva Foto"));
</script>
```

on your dialog box you see

```
Save Photo
```

Comment: Note that the bundle has been refactored, and the JS Translator now implements the same interface as in PHP. Read this for more information: https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#from-1x-to-20.